# Unwanted list item indent SwiftUI List after deleting items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

After removing all the items from a list and then adding the items back to the list, each list item is indented like it is in edit mode and swipe actions are unavailable. I only see the issue when I have the conditional checking if the array is empty.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var categories = ["dog", "cat"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if(categories.isEmpty){
                Button ("Add category"){
                    categories = ["dog", "cat"]
                }
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(categories.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text(categories[i])
                            .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                                Button(role: .destructive) {
                                    categories.remove(at: i)
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before removing items from array:

[image: before removing items]

After removing items and adding new items to array:

[image: after removing items]

Comment: Don't use `indices` as `id` for modified content, use some unique id for each model item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example that shows that deletion is not the problem

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var categories = ["dog", "cat"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if(categories.isEmpty){
                Button ("Add category"){
                    categories = ["dog", "cat"]
                }
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(categories.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text(categories[i])
//                            .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
//                                Button(role: .destructive) {
//                                    categories.remove(at: i)
//                                } label: {
//                                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
//                                }
//                            }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            categories.remove(at: i)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

the problem is that after deleting an element from the list with swipeActions the list is supposed to reposition itself, doing so just after deleting the last element from the list with swipeActions you decide to disappear the list so it will not have the time to finish his action.

I suggest the following code which works fine

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var categories = ["dog", "cat"]


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if(categories.isEmpty){
                Button ("Add category"){
                    categories = ["dog", "cat"]
                }
            }
            List {
                ForEach(categories.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text(categories[i])
                    .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                         Button(role: .destructive) {
                             categories.remove(at: i)
                         } label: {
                             Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
             // don't display if categories.isEmpty
            .frame(height: categories.isEmpty ? 0 : nil)
        }
    }}
```

[image]

Comment: Setting the frame height isn’t the best solution, the animation looks really weird then . Why not use the default EditButton and onDelete to remove items from the array.

Comment: using editButton is one solution among many others,
and my solution is also another one.
What if the guy doesn't want to have an edit button on his interface?

Everything is fine with the animation.

Comment: Hiding the frame messes with the animation, clearly. Also why make something so bland and utilize the essentials in SwiftUI. It provides more than enough to accomplish the same task but more effectively.

Comment: for animation we can add             .animation( _ , value:  )

Comment: Or add with animation inside the delete function and or move function..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. You could try using `onDelete` for this, documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/ForEach/onDelete(perform:)). I also included `onMove` if needed and added a button which is only active when the array is empty.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var animals = [
        "Dog",
        "Cat",
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(animals, id: \.self) { animal in
                    Text(animal)
                }
                .onDelete { self.delete(at :$0) }
                .onMove { self.move(from: $0, to: $1) }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Animals")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.animals = [
                            "Dog",
                            "Cat",
                        ]
                    }, label: {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }).disabled(!animals.isEmpty)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at: IndexSet) {
        for i in at {
            animals.remove(at: i)
        }
    }
    
    func move(from: IndexSet, to: Int) {
        animals.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
    }
}
```

[image]